# In java convert image to base64 gives different result on linux and Windows 10

Tags: java, arrays, image, base64

I'm trying to get base64 code from an image. There is no problem with the base64 image in Windows 10, but in Linux the image changes. Here is my code;

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
image.createGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", baos);
encodedFile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encode(baos.toByteArray()), "UTF-8");
```

On different operating systems, byteArray has different results.
If the java has a large image (like 1920x1080) on the Linux operating system, the image changes (some pixels shift and some pixels appear to have a yellow filter). Oddly enough it works fine in small image (602x339). I use java 8.
[One of the wrong converted  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txr1n.jpg)

Comment: Your image looks to me exactly like a classical read/write error. I used to work with broken Hard Disks and memory cards years ago and they look that way if they have reading errors.

Comment: What happens if you read the image file directly, with `FileInputStream`? If you only want to get the BASE64 from it, that should do as well … ok, you may have to do the image operation on the decoded BASE64 before you can display the image, but that should be transparent.

Comment: Have you compared `encodedFile` on both Windows and Linux? Are already the Strings different? If not, should have a look to your decoding …

Comment: No problem with reading, because when I upload this image with this way, there is no problem. The image looks like original one. But when I try to get Base64 format, I face this broken image error.

Comment: encodedFile is different on both windows and linux. But baos.toByteArray() is different, too. So encodedFile is different.